# Pull out tab on android app navigation drawer

Tags: tabs, galaxy

My Samsung Galaxy Duos phone has a small pull out tab on the left edge which basically pulls out a panel for quick access to Gmail, FB etc (as seen in the picture attached). I would like to do the same for my android app's navigation drawer. I tried to look it up on google and do some reading. However, I didn't get much success. Is it even possible to customize this in Android. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Samsung Galaxy Home Screen - Pull Out Tab]

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). Just on each item in ListView put action to start new Activity via Intent. Other things are pure cosmetic.